# Why 'Received' header fields are missed in Outlook message?

Tags: email, outlook, exchangewebservices

I use [EWS GetItem endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation-email-message) in order to get MIME content of e-mail message in Outlook. As a rule several 'Received' header fields are present at the beginning of message content. For example:

> Received: from AM6PR04CA0035.eurprd04.prod.outlook.com
> (2603:10a6:20b:92::48)  by AM6PR10MB2789.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
> (2603:10a6:20b:ac::25) with  Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
> cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.3348.15; Thu,
> 10 Sep  2020 11:36:56 +0000 Received-SPF: Pass
> (protection.outlook.com: domain of alterdomus.com  designates
> 51.137.107.73 as permitted sender)  receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=51.137.107.73;
> helo=smtpworker-in-9.xware-europe-west-1.o365.crossware.co.nz;
>
> Received: from VI1PR10MB3616.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
> ([fe80::204a:2512:2ac2:d5ef]) by VI1PR10MB3616.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
> ([fe80::204a:2512:2ac2:d5ef%3]) with mapi id 15.20.3305.031; Tue, 25 Aug 2020
> 17:51:53 +0000
>
> Received: from EUR02-AM5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com
> (104.47.4.57) by
> smtpworker-in-9.xware-europe-west-1.o365.crossware.co.nz   with
> Crossware for Office365; Thu, 10 Sep 2020 11:36:46 +0000

However in some cases those 'Received' fields are missed for some messages. As far as I understand this field is very important for spam detection. It contains information about the sender, the receiver and the received time of a message. This header is added by the receiving mail server as the top line. Depending on the number of mail servers involved, several 'Received' header fields may be included.

What can be the reason of missed 'Received' header fields inside e-mail MIME content? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Not all messages that are in a Office365 mailbox will have been routed via the Transport stack (most will). One example is the MyAnalytics Messages, the Office365 substrate generates these messages and they are created directly in the Mailbox by the substrate rather then being delivered. You can use something like the Message Header analyzer to check https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104005406?src=office&corrid=f7f9ed61-d151-4fcf-b0e2-9e3dec4a92d2&omexanonuid=034f54c1-a89b-429c-adc3-526f6f024f80&referralurl=https%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2f to check the headers it grabs the PidtagTransportheaders property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagtransportmessageheaders-canonical-property which is a more reliable way of getting the headers then trying to parse it back out of the Mime Message

Comment: Thanks for your answer Glen. However I observe this problem for messages, which are received from real people (both inside organization and external senders), not for auto generated emails. Why can it be?

Comment: Have you checked the PR_Transport_Header property with a MAPI editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy on a Message where this is happening ?. Messages in the SentItems folder would be missing these headers because they are a copy of the Message. Also are they recently received messages ?

Comment: You probably mean PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS. I can found it in MFCMapi tool for messages, which contain 'Received' MIME field as well. And for those without "Received' field I don't see such property. I noticed that all the messages inside  SentItems have described problem a long ago. But my question related to Inbox items first of all. I see such behavior both for old (e. g. received in 2017) and for recent (for this month) messages.

Comment: For one of the recent email try doing a message trace to see what happen in the transport layer